# How to show database password encrypted in standalone.xml by using Elytron (Wildfly 26.x)

Tags: passwords, wildfly, datasource, elytron

During migration to wildfly 26 in order to encrypt dbpassword of datasource I must use Elytron instead of Picketbox.
what is the best way to show database password encrypted in standalone.xml?
is it possible to get it working only by using elytron.bat?

a working example appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was because of a bug in elytron.bat in Wildfly 26.0.0 (JBEAP-23015)

By using Wildlfy 25.0.1.Final Version it was possible to create a credentialstore and add a password credential in a batch file.

```
elytron-tool.bat credential-store --create -- 
location="%appserver_home%/standalone/data/mycredstore.cs" --password StorePass

elytron-tool.bat credential-store -- 
location="%appserver_home%/standalone/data/mycredstore.cs" --password StorePass 
--add=database-pw --secret=myDBPassword
```

To refer this credential store in standalone.xml

```
<credential-stores>
  <credential-store name="mycredstore" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir" 
          path="mycredstore.cs" create="true">
  <credential-reference clear-text="StorePass"/>
 </credential-store>
</credential-stores>
```